# .net file random access recoard locking

Tags: vb.net, vb6, locking

**Summary:** In **.net** When locking a record in a random access file we cannot access records ahead of the locked record in the file.

To demonstrate the issue I have written two simple programs one opens and locks a record and the other tries to read through.

The results are that when locking record number 9 out of the 10 in the first program we are able to read records 1 and 2 but no more! The expectation (And this is our experience with VB6) is that you should be able to read all the records apart from the one you have locked.

Has anyone seen this problem? Am I doing something strange? Any work around?

**Demo Code:**

**Program 1 Create/Open/Lock**

```
Sub Main()

    Dim FileName As String = "test.a"
    Dim ListofName() As String = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4",
            "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10"}

    Try

        Dim FileNumber1 As Integer = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(FileNumber1, FileName, OpenMode.Random,
                 OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared, 600)

        FileGet(FileNumber1, People, 1)

        'Create File if needs be
        If People.Name = "" Then
            For A = 1 To 10
                People.Name = ListofName(A - 1)
                FilePut(FileNumber1, People, A)
            Next
        End If

        'Lock the recoard we want for testing
        Lock(FileNumber1, 9)

    Catch ex As Exception
        FileClose()
    End Try
    FileClose()
End Sub
```

_

**Program 2 Open and try and read**

```
Sub Main()

    Dim FileName As String = "C:\**Location of first program file**\test.a"

    Try

        Dim FileNumber1 As Integer = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(FileNumber1, FileName, OpenMode.Random,
                 OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared, 600)

        FileGet(FileNumber1, People, 2)

        'See  how much of the file we can read
        For A = 1 To 10
            FileGet(FileNumber1, People, A)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(People.Name.ToString)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        FileClose()
    End Try
    FileClose()
End Sub
```

Edit 0.1: We have found that the deeper an individual record is locked within the file the more bytes/records are inaccessible before the locked one.

Comment: urg... start using System.IO. Anyway, file aren't always "fully" written right away you need to close or flush the stream.

Comment: Why the vb6 tag? vb6 !=vb.net.

Comment: Might be a bug in the compatibility library; documented behavior is for `Lock` to only lock the single record.

Comment: What is the size of the people object?  Is it exactly 600 bytes?

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks, I believe we have tested with System.IO and we get the same issue (when locking one record the preceding few are not accessible by other separate processes) If you would like I can also post demo code for that to show. As for 'Fully' written I will investigate that when back in the office next week but as the two separate bits of code above are run in separate dev instances I am not sure this is the case. The error returned is one suggesting locking rather than end of file error of similar.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru Thanks, used the VB6 tag as the behaviour we are expecting during record locking was that of doing the same thing in VB6 (where all records are accessible apart from the locked record.) If this is an incorrect use of tags happy to remove it. :)

Comment: @Craig Thanks, Yeah we are thinking something similar, that .net is not locking individual records correctly at file level. But we hoped there was a work around or at least to confirm the issue especially as this is quite old ground and someone must have come across it back when MS did the whole 'lets dump vb6 and reinvent the wheel' thing!

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks, Yeah 600, as you can see in the first program if there is nothing there the file is created and populated explicitly as part of the demo. Record length was one of our thoughts too but we would not be able to read the file and individual records if we had got that wrong before even trying to lock etc..

Comment: My VB experience is mostly VB6 and older, but there is another way in those versions to access records randomly and that is to open the file in binary mode.  You can still access records in random order, and the lock might be more specific, assuming that .Net has carried forward this variation.  Look here for a [VB 6 example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/56171-file-handling-in-visual-basic-6-part-2-binary-file-handling/)

Comment: I wanted to add that the probable reason for the lock problem is more O/S related than anything - As hard disk sizes increased, locking just a few bytes or even hundred bytes was not as easy as locking an entire cluster (typically 2kb in size) which unfortunately also locks nearby records.  I'm thinking and hoping that the Binary Access method above might solve the issue, but it could be the same.

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks, nice idea, we tested today running the dev environments on an xp O/S rather then Windows 10 and got the same result. Not able to confirm if the bytes which were locked where the same but we where not able to read proceeding records. As for using binary access I think this has been tested as showing the same result by using filestream and binary reader but will confirm.

Comment: I just came across the Win32 LockFile / LockFileEx functions.  Maybe you could try working with them directly?  I would imagine that the VB compatibility library is using them under the hood to implement its record locking functionality.

Comment: @Craig thanks, yeah that's our feeling, that getfile etc uses .net native fuctions under the bonnet. We have tested those and found the same issue. See answer for .... the answer thanks to MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments.

Posted the same question over on MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7699b795-20d9-47e9-8204-5a4490698ef0/net-file-random-access-recoard-locking?forum=vbgeneral) and managed to get the answer.

> So the conclusion is that with .net if you use FileGet or (e.g. System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadDouble()) the reader not only reads what you want but also buffers content meaning that a locked record ahead within the file is hit causing read failure.
>
> But when using System.IO.FileStream.Read() and specifying exactly the number of bytes you want the buffer is not created allowing you to read all the records in a file except the locked one

Code example:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, Pack:=1)>
Structure Person
   <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=600)>
   <VBFixedString(600)>
   Dim name As String
End Structure

. . .

Using fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, Marshal.SizeOf(People))
 For A = 1 To 10
  Try
     Console.WriteLine("Trying " & A & "...")

     Dim b() As Byte
     ReDim b(Marshal.SizeOf(People) - 1)
     fs.Seek((A - 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(People), SeekOrigin.Begin)
     fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)
     Dim h = GCHandle.Alloc(b, GCHandleType.Pinned)
     People = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of Person)(h.AddrOfPinnedObject())
     h.Free()
     Console.WriteLine(People.name.Trim())

  Catch ex As Exception
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR " & A & " " & ex.Message)
  End Try
 Next
End Using
```